# overwrite file in ftp rename command

Tags: c#, iis, ftp

I have a ftp application. This application uses ftp rename command. If a file already exists in a directory which the file is renamed to, the error message 'the file not avaliable' caught. What can I do in c# to overwrite a file? In IIS there is a setting for this. When I do this, there is no problem.But,can I do this from c#?

Comment: Do you use the **FtpWebRequest.RenameTo** property?

Comment: Yes, I use FtpWebRequest.RenameTo property.

Answer (score 2):

What happens when there is a name collision depends on the server, if you cannot configure a known behaviour on each server you connect to you need to deal with it manually.

Either attempt a rename, catch the exception, delete the file then rename again or check for the files existence first (by requesting it size for example) and deleting it if found.